# Hover on one div, use jQuery to slide in another div from right

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<div class="holdingbox">
 <div class="leftbox">Stuff</div>
 <div class="rightbox">Stuff to reveal</div>
</div>
```

holdinbox has overflow of hidden
leftbox is left floated
rightbox is right floated and all the way outside of the holdingbox except for the edge (just enough so it looks like a tab).

On hover of holdingbox, I want rightbox to slide in (it will have an answer to a question in leftbox).  When mouse is moved away rightbox slides back out.

I know I need jQuery for this but I'm a bit stumped on how to use hover on one div to slide in another div from the right.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ewNpL/1/)?

You just need to do some calculations of your `div`s widths and animate a container properly.  Good luck.

Comment: I marked this as the answer at it seems to work best for what I need...thanks!  One question:  This slides in the green DIV but slides out the RED...is there a way to slide in the green over top of the red (the red stays in place)?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.holdingbox').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('div.rightbox').animate(
        { 'margin-top': '-100px' }
    ); 
});
```

And you can play with the exact animation